# Task Module Shows blank teams with validDomain

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, botframework, microsoft-teams

so I send an adaptive card with submitting action on my bot framework, that submit action have invoked action. When the TaskModuleContinueResponse is set to card the task module is working fine, but when I Used my NRGROK URL for the TaskModuleContinueResponse it will only show blank. I already add my NGROK URL in the valid domains, when I see the NGROK inspect I don't see my page being called.
Here is my manifest

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/json-schemas/teams/v1.9/MicrosoftTeams.schema.json",
  "manifestVersion": "1.9",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "id": "1c07cd26-a088-4db8-8928-ace382fa219f",
  "packageName": "Some.microsoft.teams.companycommunicator.authors",
  "developer": {
    "name": "Some",
    "websiteUrl": "https://somewebsite.com",
    "privacyUrl": "https://somewebsite.com",
    "termsOfUseUrl": "https://somewebsite.com"
  },
  "icons": {
    "color": "color.png",
    "outline": "outline.png"
  },
  "name": {
    "short": "Announce (Authors)",
    "full": "Company Announce (Authors)"
  },
  "description": {
    "short": "Broadcast messages to multiple teams and people in one go",
    "full": "Broadcasts messages to multiple teams and individuals through channel posts and chat messages"
  },
  "accentColor": "#64A2CC",
  "configurableTabs": [
    {
      "configurationUrl": "https://b0837b7151f7.ngrok.io/configtab",
      "canUpdateConfiguration": true,
      "scopes": [
        "team"
      ],
      "context": [
        "channelTab"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "bots": [
    {
      "botId": "eae687a6-936c-4fd7-ade7-1f01b388ac16",
      "scopes": [
        "team"
      ],
      "commandLists": [
        {
          "scopes": [
            "team"
          ],
          "commands": [
            {
              "title": "Test",
              "description": "Test bot trigger"
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "supportsFiles": true,
      "isNotificationOnly": false
    }
  ],
  "permissions": [
    "identity",
    "messageTeamMembers"
  ],
  "validDomains": [
    "b0837b7151f7.ngrok.io",
  ],
  "webApplicationInfo": {
    "id": "eae687a6-936c-4fd7-ade7-1f01b388ac16",
    "resource": "api://b0837b7151f7.ngrok.io"
  }
}
```

and here is my code for the task module I using ASP Net core

```
protected override async Task<TaskModuleResponse> OnTeamsTaskModuleFetchAsync(ITurnContext<IInvokeActivity> turnContext, TaskModuleRequest taskModuleRequest, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var reply = MessageFactory.Text("OnTeamsTaskModuleFetchAsync TaskModuleRequest: " + JsonConvert.SerializeObject(taskModuleRequest));
    await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(reply);

    return new TaskModuleResponse
    {
        Task = new TaskModuleContinueResponse
        {
            Value = new Microsoft.Bot.Schema.Teams.TaskModuleTaskInfo()
            {
                //Card = CreateAdaptiveCardAttachment(),
                Url = "https://b0837b7151f7.ngrok.io/details",
                FallbackUrl = "https://b0837b7151f7.ngrok.io/details",
                Height = 800,
                Width = 1000,
                Title = "Details",
            },
        },
    };
}
```

And for my page is just simple hello world.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import * as microsoftTeams from "@microsoft/teams-js";

export default class SeeDetail extends Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        microsoftTeams.initialize();
    }
    
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <center>
                    <h1>Hello World</h1>
                </center>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

I don't know why like its been blocked or something because I don't see any request to my page on the NGROK Inspect. Is there something missing here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried with your code it's working.

[image]

Please check in browser is your react page rendering correctly in browser when you call using `https://b0837b7151f7.ngrok.io/details` and try to render a page by generating a new ngrok Url.

Also check by adding your react page url in [task module working sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/1dca44e69c754d4045fbddab23797f43f4305612/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/54.teams-task-module/Bots/TeamsTaskModuleBot.cs#L36).

If the issue still persists then try by deleting the existing app and upload your manifest again in teams App studio.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Maybe I need to reupload the manifest. I'm not trying that before

Comment: Do you know what the problem was?

Answer (score 0):

I believe for adaptive cards that you have to register any submit urls with the actionable messages dashboard here https://outlook.office.com/connectors/oam/publish

Comment: Hi @Paddymac, do you have the link for the document for that submission thanks?

Comment: @Theodorus Agum Gumilang - Please go through this working [sample code](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/54.teams-task-module). It may help you.

Comment: @Mamatha-MSFT okay let me see this, but do I really need to add my URL here https://outlook.office.com/connectors/oam/publish? I don't see that step on the documentation and it should be worked on react app right?

Comment: @TheodorusAgumGumilang apologies for the late response. I couldn't find the guide I was using but I think that url portal may be specifically for rendering the card via emails and if thats the case, apologies for giving you wrong info!

Comment: @Mamatha-MSFT hi I'm kinda lost here, why my page won't load but the sample able to load. What is the requirement so I can use the page for the task module. I already Init the ms teams in the ComponentDidMount. Or it doesn't work for the react js?

Comment: @TheodorusAgumGumilang - Can you please check, when you open your page using following url in browser "https://b0837b7151f7.ngrok.io/details" is the page displaying?

Comment: @Mamatha-MSFT yes it displaying, I'm using the Azure web app bot for the bot registration, I don't know if there is any additional security on that. But it already works using deployed web. I just curious why it doesn't work on my NGROK. I'm assuming it because of security reasons because I can't see the request on the NGROK log.